# Recovering Ubuntu after installing Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, data-recovery

I had 3 SSDs in my system, each one with an own OS. Two with Windows and one with Ubuntu. I wanted to reinstall Windows on one disk and accidentally installed it on the Ubuntu drive. Is there any chance to get at least some files back?

I found a lot of questions about boot problems after installing Windows besides Ubuntu, but I totally screwed up and installed it over my Ubuntu partition. I used a Live System to check if I could find any files left but that was not the case. Boot-Repair gave me this system info:

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p2
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda4
OS#3:   Windows 10 on sdb3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0006,0003,0001,0002,0000,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,d99febcc-857f-40f1-b40b-2c394f7a88cf,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........q.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.7.0. .E.V.O. .P.l.u.s. .5.0.0.G.B....................A...........................%8Y..}......4..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.4.E.V.N.F.0.M.9.3.5.6.0.1.F........BO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.6.0. .E.V.O. .5.0.0.G.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.S.B.X.J.N.N.0.0.2.9.3.4.0. .E. . . . ........BO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.6.0. .E.V.O. .5.0.0.G.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.S.2.Z.B.N.K.1.9.3.2.8.6.7. .Y. . . . ........BO
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,9a3c22f7-7bcb-4c98-9cfd-d7b91e59897f,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,9a3c22f7-7bcb-4c98-9cfd-d7b91e59897f,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk Extreme 0001    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)/CDROM(1,0x4c8f30,0x7c00)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: SanDisk Extreme 0001, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x56f48570,0x4c8f30,0x1f00)..BO
Boot0006* USB   BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........k.S.a.n.D.i.s.k. .E.x.t.r.e.m.e. .0.0.0.1....................A.......................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.A.A.0.1.1.0.1.9.1.2.1.5.3.0.0.8.4.6.2.6........BO

78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda2/Boot/bootx64.efi
2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sda2/Boot/fbx64.efi
256fe27540b54b71cf38110338247688   sda2/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
5083a037078124a640e8dd1682fbbddb   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
3c080490d0eb8fdb738f298c3e44b3e0   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
da7c9088c9d0bff4ac469abdfc8f540e   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
e69be5ddc7c4165e0f3e5ee05d267ec2   sdb1/Boot/bootx64.efi
e69be5ddc7c4165e0f3e5ee05d267ec2   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
5a0ceb06ab09d5c2be36b38bcb33617f   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda4    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sdb4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: B0EB0099-430D-4F35-BCE6-2C7640D6B09F
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p2     34816 975674024 975639209 465.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p3 975675392 976771071   1095680   535M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 3C285DEE-80B0-4B34-B34C-F745C4B2E62B
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sdb2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sdb3     239616 975716159 975476544 465.1G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  975716352 976771071   1054720   515M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 46DCBE78-305C-40DA-A3D2-567919DA0FF4
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
sda2    1024000   1226751    202752    99M EFI System
sda3    1226752   1259519     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda4    1259520 975675429 974415910 464.7G Microsoft basic data
sda5  975677440 976771071   1093632   534M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdc: 29.84 GiB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x56f48570
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *          0  5439487  5439488  2.6G  0 Empty
sdc2       5017392  5025327     7936  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdc3       5439488 62533295 57093808 27.2G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 860:;
1:1049kB:524MB:523MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
2:524MB:628MB:104MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
3:628MB:645MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
4:645MB:500GB:499GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:500GB:500GB:560MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
sdb:500GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 860:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:500GB:499GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:500GB:500GB:540MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
sdc:32.0GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:SanDisk Extreme:;
nvme0n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB:;
1:1049kB:17.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:17.8MB:500GB:500GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
3:500GB:500GB:561MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                     
├─sda1      ntfs     92B65F4DB65F30C9                     60c88ee5-3acd-47bb-b74a-819f32c2ac27 Wiederherstellung        Basic data partition
├─sda2      vfat     385F-FBB8                            9a3c22f7-7bcb-4c98-9cfd-d7b91e59897f                          EFI system partition
├─sda3                                                    c0fa3079-5add-4298-9ee9-23cc09ff5eab                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda4      ntfs     DC3A644E3A6427AA                     ba8094e8-4b5d-4e7b-b030-fcb317ab74aa                          Basic data partition
└─sda5      ntfs     D0A81CB2A81C9954                     26757da1-613b-4bf3-aaa1-7e998e0b027f                          
sdb                                                                                                                     
├─sdb1      vfat     7C67-F723                            d99febcc-857f-40f1-b40b-2c394f7a88cf                          EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                                    a58fab26-666f-440a-9a2f-61cfb5c866c7                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3      ntfs     7E2E6E752E6E25FD                     35a89080-37a4-477a-aeb9-4092e7dc22b0                          Basic data partition
└─sdb4      ntfs     AE14D57314D53F51                     b5837c4d-6139-4088-bcb2-b3f8264a6b39                          
sdc         iso9660  2020-07-31-16-51-12-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdc1      iso9660  2020-07-31-16-51-12-00               56f48570-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdc2      vfat     C26E-047E                            56f48570-02                                                   
└─sdc3      ext4     4b3684ad-4ce6-4598-845e-319892c5fe34 56f48570-03                          writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1                                               f2c51f96-d8d9-40bc-9d70-4b8653a30966                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs     E29E297D9E294AFD                     b1f16909-e286-4b5b-879d-9746a22b851a                          Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     02664AC5664AB965                     c35a9ba6-feb5-4aaa-a0b2-509da404dd17                          

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                                                          Avail Use% Mounted on
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-01-29.0/crash]  25.3G   0% /var/crash
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-01-29.0/log]    25.3G   0% /var/log
nvme0n1p2                                                166.3G  64% /media/ubuntu/E29E297D9E294AFD
nvme0n1p3                                                 69.2M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
sda1                                                     488.8M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2                                                      63.9M  33% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda4                                                      69.1G  85% /media/ubuntu/DC3A644E3A6427AA
sda5                                                      87.7M  84% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sdb1                                                      69.6M  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
sdb3                                                     443.9G   5% /media/ubuntu/7E2E6E752E6E25FD
sdb4                                                      88.6M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
sdc1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-01-29.0/crash] rw,relatime
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-01-29.0/log]   rw,relatime
nvme0n1p2                                                ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p3                                                ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda1                                                     ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda2                                                     rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda4                                                     ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5                                                     ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb1                                                     rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sdb3                                                     ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb4                                                     ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdc1                                                     ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 00b6df01-194c-4efb-8317-c8b85c3727fd root hd1,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================


/dev/nvme0n1p1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/nvme0n1p3: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001

/dev/sda1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001

/dev/sda2: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sda3: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sda5: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001

/dev/sdb1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sdb2: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sdb4: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001
Unknown BootLoader on sdc

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  f4 8d 05 00 00 00 00 00  70 85 f4 56 00 00 80 00  |........p..V....|
000001c0  01 00 00 a5 e0 ff 00 00  00 00 00 00 53 00 00 fe  |............S...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff 30 8f  4c 00 00 1f 00 00 00 97  |......0.L.......|
000001e0  46 52 83 83 ff 34 00 00  53 00 b0 2e 67 03 00 00  |FR...4..S...g...|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[177146]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 19901: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

Ubuntu was on the 'sdb' disk. No idea why there is grub on 'sda' and still the ubuntu Boot-option...

I fear it is not possible to recover any data without a boot table or file system table... but maybe you guy have an idea.

Cheers agi

**------ EDIT #1 -------**

I ran a deep search with testdisk and got this log. I can't see anything relevant left. Just wondering what that HFS partitaion and all these LVM mgic values are...

[testdisk.log](https://file.io/kZojlZW9iwlc)

Comment: You *might* be able to extract some data using the `testdisk` utility and specifying that the device used to be `ext4` (or whatever your previous partitions were formatted as), but if any data has been written over the previous information or if the SSD has issued a TRIM command — which is highly likely — then that data is pretty much gone and non-recoverable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Pls look at my edit for the testdisk.log. Can you sport anything relevant? Do you think it is possible to recover some files with PhotoRec?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Hey thx for the link. I tried PhotoRec and R-Linux so for to recover files independent of the current partition. Unfortunately only the current Windows files were found. Can you recommend any tool? I had 500GB of files - now only 20GB are used by the new Windows system. So I have still some hope to recover files from the now unused space...